# javacv: Iterating CvSeq in Java

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

I use:

`cvFindContours(gray, mem, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));`

and as the result I have `CvSeq contours` to iterate (as far as I understand it).
So I use it like that:

```
if(contours!=null) {
  for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) {
    //..do sth with ptr
  }
}
```

It works, but from time to time (quite often) I get:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException: This pointer address is NULL.
at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSeq.h_next(Native Method)
at pl..filter(FullFilter.java:69)
at pl..Window$1.run(Window.java:41)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The line in which the exception is thrown is the line with ptr.h_next().
I tried to check for nulls but it doesn't work:

```
System.out.println("PTR="+ptr); // it's not null here!
if(ptr.h_next()==null) //exception in this line!
    System.out.println("NULL");
System.out.println(ptr.h_next());
```

The first line shows:
      `PTR=com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSeq[address=0x0,position=0,limit=1,capacity=1,deallocator=com.googlecode.javacpp.Pointer$NativeDeallocator@66d53ea4]`

I tried also invoking `contours.total()` but it always throws the same exception.
So, what is a proper way to use in Java such C-like sequences?

**EDIT:** 
my full method:

```
    public IplImage filter(IplImage image) {
        IplConvKernel kernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(2,2,1,1,CV_SHAPE_RECT, null);
        cvDilate(image, image, kernel, 1);
        kernel = cvCreateStructuringElementEx(5,5,2,2,CV_SHAPE_RECT, null);
        cvErode(image, image, kernel, 1);
        IplImage resultImage = cvCloneImage(image);
        IplImage gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(image), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1); 
        cvCvtColor(image, gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
        CvMemStorage mem = CvMemStorage.create();
        CvSeq contours = new CvSeq();
        CvSeq ptr = new CvSeq();
        cvThreshold(gray, gray, 20, 255, opencv_imgproc.CV_THRESH_BINARY);
        double thresh = 20;
        Canny( gray, gray, thresh, thresh*2, 3 ,true);
        cvFindContours(gray, mem, contours, Loader.sizeof(CvContour.class) , CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, cvPoint(0,0));

        int i=0;
        CvRect boundbox;
        if(contours!=null) {
            for (ptr = contours; ptr != null; ptr = ptr.h_next()) { //EXCEPTION HERE!
                System.out.println((i++)+"\t"+ptr);
                cvDrawContours( resultImage, ptr, CvScalar.BLUE, CvScalar.RED, -1, 3, 8, cvPoint(0,0) );
                System.out.println("PTR="+ptr);
            }

        }       
        return resultImage;
    }
```

It works fine for some time and suddenly (probably when no contours found?) it ends with the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.NullPointerException: This pointer address is NULL.
    at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSeq.h_next(Native Method)
    at pl.kasprowski.eyetracker.FullFilter2.filter(FullFilter2.java:39)
    at pl.kasprowski.eyetracker.Window$1.run(Window.java:42)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Im feeding the method directly with images taken from camera (once a second).

**EDIT:**

After some experiments it occurs that from time to time when I invoke `cvFindContours` as above I get a `contour` object which IS NOT NULL but invoking any method like `contour.h_next()` or `contour.total()` results in exception like above. What can be wrong? Or - how to check if the `contour` object is OK?! Of course I could catch `NullPointerException` but I don't think it's a correct way to solve the problem...

Comment: Hi, Can you show tell full "run" function , what exactly its is doing along with Exception line no.? As what your are doing is correct . Some other things may causing the problem.

Comment: I added the full code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.
I added additional condition. Instead of:

```
if(contours!=null) {
```

I wrote

```
if(contours!=null && !contours.isNull()) {
```

and it works. I don't see exactly why it is necessary but I think it's connected with Java <-> C semantic gap.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to use `cvGetSeqElem(contours, i)`

Example :

```
for (int i = 0; i < contours.total(); i++) {
   CvRect rect = cvBoundingRect(cvGetSeqElem(contours, i),0);
    //....... Your code ....//

}
```

Comment: When using: `CvRect rect = cvBoundingRect(cvGetSeqElem(contours, j),0);` I got: `The method cvBoundingRect(opencv_core.CvArr, int) in the type opencv_imgproc is not applicable for the arguments (Pointer, int)`